# Flask rendering two forms in different files but can get only the first form

Tags: python, flask, wtforms

I am trying to upload a csv file into Mysql with choosing the correspanding columns but the problem is that once I change the route, the file is closed.
So I tried to render 2 templates in the same route: the first to load the file and the second to choose the columns. I can access only the first template.
I am testing the second form with env.is_submitted() but even when I am not submitting it prints "submitted"

```
    @app.route('/upload', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
    def upload():
    form = UploadForm()
    global columnscsv, salessource
    if form.validate_on_submit():
       try:
         filename = secure_filename(form.csv.data.filename)
         file = form.csv.data

         if file and allowed_file(filename):                  
           print 'file_path'                   
           salessource = CSVSource(file, delimiter=',')   
           columnscsv = salessource.fieldnames 
           print columnscsv

       finally:  
           return render(salessource)  
    return render_template('upload.html', form=form)

    def render(salessource):
        env = envForm() 
        if env.is_submitted():
           print "submitted"
        return  render_template('form.html',columnscsv = columnscsv ,env =env)
```

upload.html

```
    <html>
    <head>
     <title>Upload</title>
      </head>
     <body>
      <form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" >
      {{ form.hidden_tag() }}
      {{ form.csv }}
      <input type="submit">
    </form></body>
     </html>
```

form.html

```
        {% block body %}
        <form   name = "mapping" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data" >
           {{ env.hidden_tag() }}
            <table>
        {% for csv in columnscsv %}
        <tr> <td> {{ csv }}</td>
             <td><select name = "{{ csv }}" >       
             <option >year </option>
             <option >month</option>
             <option >day</option>       
             <option>reference</option>
             <option>designation</option>
             </select></td>
        </tr>
        {% endfor %}
        </table>
            <input type="submit" value="Submit" name = "submit" >
            </form>

        {% endblock %}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your form.html can only be rendered when you submit a form (your `render(salessource)` was inside the check of submit form), so I cant find anyway it does not print "Submitted" in this way.

If you want to render 2 templates, I find a work arround like this:

- Add `session['fileName'] = filename` as a temp to know if a file was submitted
- Redirect back to itself after submit
- Check if `session['fileName']` exist to choose what template to render

  ```
  @app.route('/upload', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
  def upload():
      form = UploadForm()
      global columnscsv, salessource
      if form.validate_on_submit():
          try:
              filename = secure_filename(form.csv.data.filename)
              file = form.csv.data
              session['fileName'] = filename

              if file and allowed_file(filename):                  
                  print 'file_path' 
                  salessource = CSVSource(file, delimiter=',')   
                  columnscsv = salessource.fieldnames 
                  print columnscsv
              redirect(url_for('upload'))
          except:
              raise

      if session.get('fileName') != None:
          render_template('form.html',columnscsv = columnscsv ,env=env)
      else:
          return render_template('upload.html', form=form)
  ```

Comment: Thank you but  I still don't get it how can I access to the form in form.html

Comment: Can you have more details about 'access'

Comment: I mean when I render template to 'form.hml' I can't get to the tags in the form. Well I found an other solution : I upload the file locally and reuse it. Thank you